# Verbes avec tableau

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes

> Dresser/Compléter/Remplir un [tableau de variations d'une fonction](http://www.mathematiques-lycee.com/2nde-02-tableau-variations.html).

1. Y a-t-il des différences ?
2. Quels autres verbes peut-on utiliser dans le même contexte ?

Comment: Il s'agit probablement d'un tableau des variations d'une fonction ; en ce cas ce serait une bonne idée de le mentionner dans le texte de la question.

Comment: @LPH merci ; c'est fait:-)!

Comment: Le texte le dit: **réaliser** un tableau de variations etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut trouver **dresser** pour un tableau mais moins que d'autres verbes. **Dresser** c'est plutôt pour une liste, un inventaire, un catalogue etc.

**Compléter** peut être employé mais en général ça implique que le tableau a déjà été commencé et qu'on veut le terminer.

**Remplir** convient :

> [tu remplis un tableau de variations et tu obtiens ainsi l'allure de la trajectoire.](https://www.ilephysique.net/sujet-cinematique-315579.html)

En plus du banal **faire** ([Dans l'étude des fonctions, il est souvent utile de faire un tableau de variations](http://math.et.info.free.fr/TikZ/Complements.html).) tu as aussi :

**Réaliser :**

> [Réaliser un tableau de variations à partir d'une courbe](http://www.mathematiques-lycee.com/2nde-02-tableau-variations.html)

**Construire :**

> [Pour construire le tableau de variations d’une fonction à
> partir de sa courbe](https://maths-bacpro.nathan.fr/9782091654072/assets/automatisme-9-fiche-5-1/preview) ...

**Établir** :

> [ils apprennent à établir un tableau de variations
> d’une fonction](https://www.education.gouv.fr/media/585/download)

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce domaine un très bon terme rest le verbe « *construire* » ; « dresser » est aussi tout à fait correct. Cependant « completer », qui a un gout d'angicisme, ne peut convenir en français que si le tableau est déjà partiellement établi. « Remplir » ne convient pas non plus parce qu'un tel tableau n'est ne commence à ressembler à un tableau que lorsq'on a déterminé les maxima et que l'on peut tracer des colonnes.